# How to prove that shortest distance between any two points is always a straight line?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

While solving a book there was a statement that prove that shortest distance between two points is always a straight line by

1. Geometry
2. Coordinate geometry

I was unable to prove it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Example

Comment: What is this book about?

Comment: I wonder if the ancient Greeks proved this using Euclidean geometry and without calculus